# Joining points together to create single line and mapping output

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I have the following data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  code=c("A00111", "A00112","A00113","A00211","A00212","A00213","A00214","A00311","A00312","A00472"),
  x=c(325147,323095,596020,257409,241206,248371,261076,595218,596678,597678),
  y=c(286151,284740,335814,079727,084266,078283,062045,333889,337836,339836),
  point_id=c("P01","P02","P03","P04","P05","P06","P07","P08","P09","P10"))

sf1 <- st_as_sf(dt1, coords = c("x","y"), crs=27700, na.fail=FALSE)
```

I would like to create a single line that joins the points together based on `point_id` (so point P01 to P02 to P03 etc.) as a new sf object. I would then like to visualise this line using tmap by appending it to something like this:

```
tmap_mode("view")
map <- tm_shape(sf1) + tm_dots()
map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you summarise your `sf1` you get a `MULTIPOINT`-object. `do_union = F` tells R not to "union" but to "combine" them, which preserves the order of the points. So you order them by the id beforehand.

Finally you cast the `MULTIPOINT` to `LINESTRING`.

```
library(tmap) 
library(sf)

sf1 %>%
  summarise(do_union = F) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") -> sf_line

tm_shape(sf_line) + tm_lines()
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been developing the [sfheaders](https://github.com/dcooley/sfheaders) library to help with this sort of thing

```
library(sfheaders)
library(sf)

## given a data.frame, call sf_linestring() and it will return an sf object of LINESTRINGS
sf <- sf_linestring(
  obj = dt1
  , x = "x"
  , y = "y"
)
sf::st_crs( sf ) <- 27700 

sf
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 241206 ymin: 62045 xmax: 597678 ymax: 339836
# epsg (SRID):    27700
# proj4string:    +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
# id                       geometry
# 1  1 LINESTRING (325147 286151, ...
```